# Update D3 pie chart with JSON

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I have this pie chart : http://jsfiddle.net/fg9MU/265/

It doesn't seem to like it when I change from a dataset of length 3, to one of length 2.

Original data:

```
var dataSet1 = [{
  "id": "001 Helicopter",
  "name": "Helicopter",
  "priority": "highClass",
  "value": 1
}, {
  "id": "005 Rear Rotor",
  "name": "Rear Rotor",
  "priority": "lowClass",
  "value": 1
}, {
  "id": "002 Rotor",
  "name": "Rotor",
  "priority": "lowClass",
  "value": 1
}]
```

Change dataset :

```
function changeData(data) {
    path.data(pie(data));
    path.transition().duration(750).attrTween("d", arcTween); // redraw the arcs

  }
```

Pass the function new data :

```
changeData(dataSet2);
```

Dataset2 :

```
var dataSet2 = [{
  "id": "001 Helicopter",
  "name": "Helicopter",
  "priority": "highClass",
  "value": 1
}, {
  "id": "004 Seat",
  "name": "Seat",
  "priority": "lowClass",
  "value": 1
}]
```

It doesn't seem to update the datasets. The one that's in both i.e 'Helicopter' adjusts fine (1/2 of the chart) but the others don't. I have seen this example : http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/5681842

It says to use this :

```
function type(d) {
  d.apples = +d.apples || 0;
  d.oranges = +d.oranges || 0;
  return d;
}
```

But I have no idea how to implement this into my dataset :( Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't handling the `enter`, `update`, `exit` pattern in your update function:

```
function changeData(data) {
    var path = svg.datum(data)
      .selectAll("path").data(pie); //<-- update selection
    path.exit().remove(); //<-- exit selectin
    path.transition().duration(750).attrTween("d", arcTween); // redraw the arcs for the paths left
  }
```

*Note*, even with this code change, you aren't handling entered items on `changeData`.  You should add `path.enter().append(...` to that function for when your data grows.

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fg9MU/273/).

Comment: Integrated the update you said so it changes properly when I add data : http://jsfiddle.net/fg9MU/274/, thanks again